# Why this 2 form dosn't work with ajax in Django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am developing an application on django, and faced with strange problems with Ajax. On my website 4 forms should be processed using Ajax. And two of them work great. But 2 others not heard 
 about Ajax at all. Consider working and non-working forms.

### views.py

*view working form*

```
def login_user(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    context = { 'form': form, }

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['user_login']
        password = form.cleaned_data['user_password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        response_data = {}
        if user and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            response_data['result'] = 'Ok'
        else:
            response_data['result'] = 'Bad'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data))  
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

*view non-working form*

```
 def add_new_station(request, add_station_slug):
        form = AddStationForm(request.POST)
        myuser = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
        print(request.user)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            response_data = {}
            UserStation.objects.create(
                station=Station.objects.get(slug=add_station_slug),
                impressions=form.cleaned_data['impressions'],
                list=UserStationsList.objects.get(user=myuser)
                response_data['result'] = 'Ok'
            )
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data)) 
        else:
           return redirect('index')
```

### urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', index, name='index'),
        path("add-in-list/<str:add_station_slug>/", add_new_station, name='new_station'),
        path('login/', login_user, name='login_action'),
        ...
]
```

### html

*html working form*

```
<form id="login_form" action="{% url 'login_action' %}" method="post">                                       
   {% csrf_token %}                                          
   {{ formlogin }}                                   
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mt-2">Entry</button> 
    </div>                                   
</form>
```

*html non-working form*

```
<form id="add_station_form" action="{% url 'new_station' choice_station.slug %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ formaddstaion }}
     <div class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mt-2">I visited this  station</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

### mian.js

*script working form*

```
$('#login_form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        type: $(this).attr('method'), 
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        success: function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(response)
            if (data['result'] === "Ok"){
              $('.login-message').hide()
              location.reload()
            }
            else{
              $('.login-message').show(100).html('wrong data')
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

*script non-working form*

```
$('#add_station_form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
          type: $(this).attr('method'), 
          url: $(this).attr('action'), 
          success: function(response) { 
              data = JSON.parse(response)
              alert('data') // try check, but ajax don't reach here
          }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

In the first case, everything works perfectly, in the second, the Ajax does not start at all (I’m just being redirect to the page with HttpResponce. So, what is the problem?

Comment: Looks most likely to me to be due to the "non-working form" not being valid when you submit it. We would need to know what you're submitting, as well as the content of the Django `form` class - but you really need some client-side validation in your submit handler, before the Ajax request is made.

Comment: But how to write this client-side validation?

Comment: In the non-working ajax request you're not posting any data? Print out request.POST in view to check what's being posted.

Comment: Good point @Borut - I'd noticed that but thought somehow that the data wasn't needed in the POST request, but now I see it is.

Comment: I printed  clien data: `My impressions: just for check
[06/Feb/2019 19:57:28] "POST /add-in-list/vladykino/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16` It seems that everything is OK - the server will receive data. The only problem is ajax

Comment: You're not sending any data in your non-working ajax. Add `data: $(this).serialize()` there as you did in your working ajax.

Comment: change this:  `url: $(this).attr('action')` to `url: '/new_station/'` and add data to your ajax like this `data: {'choice_station':'{{choice_station.slug}}'}`. then in your view you need to get the data as `request.POST.get('choice_station')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second form you are trying to send a POST request to a Django view using ajax but as we all know **POST requests don't contain parameter inside the url** so you need to remove the parameter from the url and do some necessary changes like the following:

Remove the parameter in your url and add a hidden input field to your form which will contain the parameter.

```
    <form id="add_station_form" action="{% url 'new_station' %}" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ formaddstaion }}
      <input type="hidden" name="add_station_slug" value="{{choice_station.slug}}" readonly>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success mt-2">
             I visited this  station
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Inside an ajax as [@Borut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8827624/borut) said in comments you need to pass the data to your ajax request like this:

```
    $.ajax({ 
       type: $(this).attr('method'), 
       url: $(this).attr('action'), 
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data) { alert(data.response);  }
    });
```

Now inside the urls.py remove the parameter like this:

```
    urlpatterns = [
      ...
      path("add-in-list/", add_new_station, name='new_station'),
      ...
    ]
```

Now at last inside the views you can extract your parameter and use it:

```
    from django.http import JsonResponse 
    # from Django 1.7 onward you should use JsonResponse instead of HttpResponse
    # so that you don’t need to serialize the data before returning the response object.

    def add_new_station(request):
       response_data = {'response': 'Something went wrong!'}
       form = AddStationForm(request.POST)
       myuser = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
       if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():            
          slug = request.POST.get('add_station_slug')
          UserStation.objects.create(
            station=Station.objects.get(slug=slug),
            impressions=form.cleaned_data['impressions'],
            list=UserStationsList.objects.get(user=myuser)                
          )
        response_data['response'] = 'UserStation Created Successfully!'
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Comment: @Ahtisham, sorry it's took so many time, but i treid your code, and the same result- aflet i ckicked, my page is reloaded, and I find myself on the page with the message, for some reason **ajax refuses to work**, I tried to put script it into the <script> block in the "base.html", the same result

Comment: @ Ahtisham, OFC, I think found the problem. The problem is that the “Station Details” card, on which the form for adding a station is, not on the page - the script does not see the form **because card is the get request**. So is there a way around this?